# R Shiny - how to put value and name attributes in checkboxInput?

Tags: r, shiny

I find RShiny is quite difficult to use as I can't have the control over my html, for instance,

I want to create a check box below,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="species" name="species_particles" value="particles"/>
```

in my shiny ui.R,

```
checkboxInput(inputId = "species",
                    label = "Particles",
                    value = "particles")
```

I get this error,

```
ERROR: invalid 'y' type in 'x && y'
```

I don't know what it means and how to fix it. And it does not make sense. what y? what x?

what about the name attribute? how can I put that in `checkboxInput()`?

Answer (score 1):

The argument to `value` needs to be logical and determines whether the checkbox is selected by default or not.  For example,

```
checkboxInput(inputId = "species",
                label = "Particles",
                value = TRUE)
```

See `?checkboxInput` for details.

Comment: I have checked that. but it does not say where/how to put the checkbox attributes in.

Comment: I think that `inputId` (which adds a slot to `input`) essentially performs the role of a name attribute.  The result would be accessed as `input$species` in the example given in your question.

Answer (score 1):

The thread is somewhat older, but as no answer has been accepted yet, in order to assign values to the checkboxes, simply use `checkboxGroupInput` instead of `checkboxInput`.

```
library("shiny")

runApp(list(
    ## ui.R
    ui = shinyUI(
        fluidPage(
            checkboxGroupInput(
                inputId = "species"
                , label = "Particeles"
                , choices = c("Quarks" = "Quarks", "Leptons" = "Leptons"
                , "Antiquarks" = "Antileptons"))
            , uiOutput("tmp")
        )
    )
    ## server.R
    , server = function (input, output, session) {
        output$tmp <- renderUI({
            HTML(paste("Currently selected:", 
                paste(input$species, collapse = ", ")))
        })
    }
))
```